# Uso de interpolación de angular para una propiedad CSS

Tags: css, angular, interpolacion

Trabajo con angular y bootstrap; estoy trayendo datos de mi base de datos para la confección de una barra de progreso de habilidades. Uno de esos datos es el porcentaje de la habilidad que se traduce en el grosor de la barra de progreso:

```
<div class="progress-bar barra" role="progressbar" aria-label="Example with label"
            style="width: {{habilidad.porcentaje}}%" aria-valuenow="25" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"><span
              class="porcentaje">{{habilidad.porcentaje}}%</span>
          </div>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Haciéndolo de ese modo funciona. Pero, pese a que levanta el servidor y se observa el porcentaje adecuado de las barras de progreso,angular me tira un error en el html: property value expectedcss(css-propertyvalueexpected).
Hay alguna forma más adecuada de pasarle la interpolación o el dato del porcentaje que viene de la BD?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

suponiendo que tu variable   habilidad.porcentaje esté correcto y que te devuelva un valor: te recomiendo usar la directiva ngStyle, donde quedaría de la siguiente forma. también te recomiendo revisar la documentación de angular para entender mejor  .

```html
  <div class="progress-bar barra" role="progressbar" aria-label="Example with label"
        [ngStyle]="{'width.%':habilidad.porcentaje}" aria-valuenow="25" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"><span
              class="porcentaje">{{habilidad.porcentaje}}%</span>
          </div>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias es lo que necesitaba. Sabía que debía utilizar el ngStyle. Pero recién estoy aprendiendo a usarlo. Seguiré viendo en la documentación de angular